# Problems when INSERT into DB

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

When I try to submit data into the database, the app crashes.

Here are the parts of the java file concerned with creating and inserting data into the database.

My `Contract.java` class has the following information:

```
public class Contract {
    public static abstract class customReminder{
        public static final String TABLE_NAME = "CUSTOM_REMINDER";
        public static final String ID = "ID";
        public static final String TITLE = "TITLE";
        public static final String DESCRIPTION = "DESCRIPTION";
        public static final String DATE_TIME = "DATE_TIME";

        public static final String[] REMINDER_COLUMNS = {ID, TITLE, DESCRIPTION, DATE_TIME};

    }
```

My `DBHelper.java` class:

```
//SQLite statement for custom reminder table
public static final String CUSTOM_REMINDER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + Contract.customReminder.TABLE_NAME + "("
        + Contract.customReminder.ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
        + Contract.customReminder.TITLE + " TEXT,"
        + Contract.customReminder.DESCRIPTION + " TEXT,"
        + Contract.customReminder.DATE_TIME + " TEXT,"
        + ");";

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(CUSTOM_REMINDER_TABLE);
}
```

My `CustumRemider.java` class:

```
public boolean createCustomReminder(String title, String description, String dateTime){
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(mAllColumns[1], title);
    contentValues.put(mAllColumns[2], description);
    contentValues.put(mAllColumns[3], dateTime);
    long result = mDatabase.insert(Contract.customReminder.TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    return result != -1;
}
```

I downloaded the database to my PC from Android Device Monitor and opened it with SQLiteBrowser. I notice that a table `android_metadata` is created instead of `CUSTOM_REMINDER`.

```
CREATE TABLE android_metadata (locale TEXT)
```

I neither know where the query comes from nor why it does this.

Comment: Please post LogCat error

Comment: `android_metadata` table is generated by android & it stores metadata that android needs. Is there anything else wrong? A stacktrace of the crash you get would be helpful

Comment: Did you create an instance of the SqliteOpenHelper anywhere? The table isn't created until you try to open the database connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change 
delete comma (",") after last parameter in create table query

```
public static final String CUSTOM_REMINDER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + Contract.customReminder.TABLE_NAME + "("
    + Contract.customReminder.ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
    + Contract.customReminder.TITLE + " TEXT,"
    + Contract.customReminder.DESCRIPTION + " TEXT,"
    + Contract.customReminder.DATE_TIME + " TEXT"
    + ");";
```

instead of this

```
public static final String CUSTOM_REMINDER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + Contract.customReminder.TABLE_NAME + "("
    + Contract.customReminder.ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
    + Contract.customReminder.TITLE + " TEXT,"
    + Contract.customReminder.DESCRIPTION + " TEXT,"
    + Contract.customReminder.DATE_TIME + " TEXT,"
    + ");";
```